# Split table row into two fields and count each

Tags: mysql

So far I have wrote the following query:

```
SELECT forum_topics.*, users.id as userid, users.username, users.avatar, forum_categories.name as cat_name
FROM forum_topics 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id = forum_topics.author_id
INNER JOIN forum_categories
ON forum_categories.id = forum_topics.category_id
WHERE forum_topics.id = 64
```

But I also want to add another table `votes` that has the following structure:

```
___________________________________________________________
| id | object_type | object_id | receiver | giver | type    |
___________________________________________________________
| 128| topic       |     64    |    21    |  22   | like    |
| 129| topic_reply |     55    |    21    |  22   | dislike |
___________________________________________________________
```

Basically the relation between the two tables is `forum_topics.id` from Table 1 and  `object_id` from Table 2 (the bottom one). This is for a forum and I want to display likes/dislikes for each topic and reply. `type` could be `like` and `dislike`. `receiver` is the user that made the post, `giver` is the user that voted. I want to INNER JOIN the `votes` table in the first query and count all likes and dislikes into two separate fields. Something like:

`Select votes.count(*) as likes WHERE type = 'like and votes.count(*) as dislikes WHERE type = 'dislike'`
The query got so complicated and I am so confused.

Edit: So I figured it out for `forum_topics`. Here is how I did it:

```
    SELECT forum_topics.*, users.id as userid, users.username, users.avatar, forum_categories.name as cat_name,
   count(CASE WHEN votes.type = 'like'    AND votes.object_type = 'topic'  then 1 else null end) as votes_likes, 
   count(CASE WHEN votes.type = 'dislike' AND votes.object_type = 'topic'  then 1 else null end) as votes_dislikes
FROM forum_topics 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id = forum_topics.author_id
INNER JOIN forum_categories
ON forum_categories.id = forum_topics.category_id
INNER JOIN votes 
ON votes.object_id = forum_topics.id
WHERE forum_topics.id = ?
```

Now for `forum_posts` It is not working..

```
SELECT forum_posts.*, users.id as userid, users.username, users.avatar,
      count(CASE WHEN votes.type = 'like'    AND votes.object_type = 'topic_post' then 1 else null end) as votes_likes, 
      count(CASE WHEN votes.type = 'dislike' AND votes.object_type = 'topic_post' then 1 else null end) as votes_dislikes
  FROM forum_posts
  INNER JOIN users
  ON users.id = forum_posts.author_id
  LEFT JOIN votes 
  ON votes.object_id = forum_posts.id
  WHERE forum_posts.topic_id = 64
  ORDER BY forum_posts.id
```

Any ideas how to fix it? In HeidiSQL it returns one row with everything NULL.

Comment: You probably don't want to `INNER JOIN` the votes table, as this will remove any `forum_topics` record that has no votes.

Comment: I think I managed to make it work for the `forum_topics` but as you said for `forum_posts` everything disappeared. I edited my post. Would you be able to check it please?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of forum_posts and forum_topics? Also, what's the relationship between object_type and object_id in the votes table? Can a single object_id have multiple object_types in the votes table?

Comment: [forum_posts](https://i.imgur.com/mZXgT19.png)  [forum_topics](https://i.imgur.com/Wc7DTeR.png) Here is the structure. No, there isn't other relevant values. `topic` is for the topic and `topic_posts` are the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT forum_posts.id
       , forum_posts.author_id
       , forum_posts.editor_id
       , forum_posts.topic_id
       , forum_posts.content
       , forum_posts.date_created
       , forum_posts.updated
       , users.id as userid
       , users.username
       , users.avatar
       , count(CASE WHEN votes.type = 'like' AND votes.object_type = 'topic_post' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS votes_likes
       , count(CASE WHEN votes.type = 'dislike' AND votes.object_type = 'topic_post' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS votes_dislikes
FROM forum_posts
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = forum_posts.author_id
LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.object_id = forum_posts.id
WHERE forum_posts.topic_id = 64
GROUP BY forum_posts.id
       , forum_posts.author_id
       , forum_posts.editor_id
       , forum_posts.topic_id
       , forum_posts.content
       , forum_posts.date_created
       , forum_posts.updated 
       , users.id
       , users.username
       , users.avatar
```

Answer (score 0):

try using group by;

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*) 
FROM votes 
GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: Can you give me and example?